# Interaction between neutrino and an anti-neutrino?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, neutrinos

What happens when a neutrino and an anti-neutrino interacts together? For example, what does a muon neutrino and anti-muon neutrino produce? it says in my book that it creates "muons and antimuons". But, how? Don't the particle and the antiparticle annihilate when they interact with each other?

Comment: It seems like you're asking two separate questions here. Could you edit this post to only contain one of them, and post the other one separately?

Comment: @DavidZ Thanks for the advice. Can you try to answer my question, please?

Answer (score 5):

If you are asking about an interaction between a $\nu_\mu$ and a $\bar{\nu}_\mu$, then they annihilate to a (generally off-shell) $Z^0$-boson and which then decays to some particle/anti-particle pair. The pair may be charged leptons, neutrinos or quarks (assuming there is enough energy to hadronize) so the final outcome could be a lot of different things. 
$$ \nu_\mu + \bar{\nu}_\mu \to Z^{0*} \to \text{a pair of some kind}\,.$$

This is analogous to the process known as Drell-Yan when the intermediate boson is a photon, only the cross-section is much lower on account of being weak moderated.

Comment: Additionally if the neutrino is a Majorana particle then they may vanish to nothing in certain processes.

Comment: @jazzwhiz Well, yes, but they have to be off-shell in the first place for that.